# Desinstalar o Django

Tags: django, instalador

Tentei instalar o `Django` no Lubuntu, mas fiz bobagem. Quero primeiro desinstalar e depois instalar da forma correta. Portanto são duas questões:

- Como desinstalar corretamente o `Django` do Lubuntu?
- Como instalar corretamente o `Django` no Lubuntu?

Comment: Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo stackoverflow, conheça um pouco das regras e boas práticas.

Answer (score 2):

### **Desinstalar**

**Usando `pip`**

Instalar o `python-pip`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Remover `django` usando `pip`:

```
sudo pip uninstall Django
```

Desinstalar o `python-pip`:

```
sudo apt-get remove python-pip
```

**Usando o `shell` `Python`**:

Use o shell `Python` para descobrir o caminho do `Django`:

```
 >>> import django >>> django <module 'django' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.pyc'>
```

Em seguida, remove manualmente:

```
 sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/
```

### **Instalar**

Há várias maneiras diferentes para instalar o `Django`, dependendo de suas necessidades e como você deseja configurar seu ambiente de desenvolvimento. Estes têm diferentes vantagens e um método pode prestar-se melhor à sua situação específica do que outros.

Alguns dos diferentes métodos são abaixo:

- Instalar a partir de pacotes: Os repositórios oficiais do Ubuntu contém pacotes `Django` que pode ser instalado facilmente com o convencional `apt` gerenciador de pacotes. Isto é muito simples, mas não é tão flexível como alguns outros métodos. Além disso, a versão contida nos repositórios podem ficar para trás das versões oficiais disponíveis a partir do projeto.
- Através `pip`: O `pip` ferramenta é um gerenciador de pacotes para pacotes `Python`. Se você instalar `pip` , você pode facilmente instalar `Django` no nível do sistema para ser utilizado por qualquer usuário. Isto deve conter sempre a última versão estável. Mesmo assim, as instalações globais são inerentemente menos flexível.
- Instalar por meio `pip` em um `Virtualenv`: O `Python` `virtualenv` pacote permite criar ambientes independentes para vários projetos. Usando esta tecnologia, você pode instalar o `Django` em um diretório do projeto sem afetar o maior sistema. Isso permite que você fornecer personalizações e pacotes por projeto facilmente. Os ambientes virtuais adicionar alguma ligeira sobrecarga mental e processo em comparação com globalmente de instalação acessível, mas fornecem a maior flexibilidade.
- Instalar através `git`: Se você deseja instalar a versão mais recente desenvolvimento em vez da versão estável, você terá que adquirir o código do `git repo`. Isso é necessário para obter as mais recentes funcionalidades `/` correções e pode ser feito a nível global ou local. As versões de desenvolvimento não têm as mesmas garantias de estabilidade, no entanto.

**A partir de pacotes**

Se você deseja instalar `Django` usando os repositórios do `Ubuntu`, o processo é muito simples. Primeiro, atualize a sua lista local de pacotes com `apt`, em seguida, instalar o `python-django` pacote:

```
 sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install python-django
```

Você pode testar se a instalação foi bem sucedida, escrevendo:

```
 django-admin --version
```

**Através do `pip`**

Se você deseja instalar a versão mais recente do `Django` globalmente, a melhor opção é usar `pip` , o gerenciador de pacotes `Python`. Em primeiro lugar, é preciso instalar o `pip` gerenciador de pacotes.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Agora você pode instalar `pip`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip // Python 2
sudo apt-get install python3-pip // Python 3
```

Agora que você tem `pip`, pode facilmente instalar `Django`.

```
sudo pip install django // Python 2
sudo pip3 install django // Python 3
```

Você pode verificar se a instalação foi bem-sucedida, escrevendo:

```
django-admin --version
```

**Por meio `pip` em um `Virtualenv`**

Vamos começar com a instalação de pip a partir dos repositórios do Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install python-pip  // Python 2
sudo apt-get install python3-pip  // Python 3
```

Com o `pip` instalado, você pode usá-lo para instalar o `virtualenv` pacote.

```
sudo pip install virtualenv // Python 2
sudo pip3 install virtualenv // Python 2
```

Agora, sempre que você iniciar um novo projeto, você pode criar um ambiente virtual para ele. Comece criando e movendo-se em um novo diretório do projeto:

```
mkdir ~/ newproject cd ~/ newproject
```

Agora, crie um ambiente virtual dentro do diretório do projeto, escrevendo:

```
virtualenv newenv
```

Isto irá instalar uma versão independente do `Python`, bem como `pip`, em uma estrutura de diretório isolado dentro do seu diretório do projeto. Aqui o nosso ambiente virtual é chamado de `newenv`, você pode escolher esse nome. Um diretório será criado com o nome que você escolher, e irá realizar a hierarquia de arquivos onde seus pacotes serão instalados.

Para instalar pacotes no ambiente isolado, você deve ativá-lo digitando:

```
source newenv /bin/activate
```

Seu prompt deve mudar para refletir que você está agora em seu ambiente virtual. Ele será parecido com `( newenv )username@hostname:~/newproject$` .

Em seu novo ambiente, você pode usar o `pip` para instalar `Django`. Independentemente de saber se você está usando a versão 2 ou 3 do Python, ele deve ser chamado apenas `pip` quando você está em seu ambiente virtual. Além disso, note que você não precisa usar `sudo` desde que você está instalando localmente:

```
pip install django
```

Você pode verificar a instalação, digitando:

```
django-admin --version
```

Para deixar o seu ambiente virtual, é preciso emitir o `deactivate` comando de qualquer lugar no sistema:

```
deactivate
```

O seu prompt deve reverter para a tela convencional. Quando você deseja trabalhar em seu projeto novamente, você deve reativar seu ambiente virtual, movendo de volta para o diretório do projeto e ativação:

```
cd ~/ newproject source newenv /bin/activate
```

**Através `git`**

Se precisar de uma versão de desenvolvimento do `Django`, você terá que baixar e instalar `Django` a partir do seu `git` repositório. Para fazer isso, você precisará instalar o `git` em seu sistema com `apt`.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Para instalar git:

```
sudo apt-get install git python-pip // Python 2
sudo apt-get install git python3-pip // Python 3
```

Depois de ter `git`, você pode clonar o repositório `Django`:

```
git clone git://github.com/django/django ~/django-dev
```

Uma vez que o repositório é clonado, você pode instalá-lo usando `pip` . Nós vamos usar o `-e` opção para instalar no modo "editável", que é necessário durante a instalação do controle de versão.

```
sudo pip install -e ~/django-dev // Python 2
sudo pip3 install -e ~/django-dev // Python 3
```

Você pode verificar se a instalação foi bem-sucedida:

```
django-admin --version
```

[Versão em inglês desse tutorial de instalação](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: Cara, o artigo ficou sensacional! Simplesmente perfeito. Parabéns! Me ajudou bastante.